# Jasmine.js - Spec not running

Tags: javascript, jasmine, require, karma-runner

I have been to configure a Jasmine/Karma/Require setup for a few days now.  I have my karma server watching a spec file.  When the spec file changes, I can see the server logging that the files are running, but I never get inside my spec, just to the beginning of it.  Here is my spec file:

```
require(['models/Patient'], function(Patient) {
  describe('Patient', function () {
      it('cannot be null', function () {
        var patient = new Patient();
          expect(patient).not.toBeUndefined();
          expect(3).toBe(2);
      });
  });
});
```

If I put a `debugger` before the require statement, it gets hit, but it never makes it past the require statement.  What could be some causes that would make the code stop there?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the problem you are describing is a result of the module "models/Patient" never getting loaded but requirejs. My advice would be to post the require configuration and a snippet of your folder structure so we can help.